# Different dropdowns with same source giving same value. How to handle?

Tags: asp.net, datatable, dropdown

I've bound three drop down lists with same oledb data adapter. this oledbdataadapter fills three different datatables which I use eventually to fill up three dropdowns. But when I access three dropdown values in submit button, all three dropdowns give same selected item even when I've selected three different options in dropdowns. Can Anybody help?
here's my code:-

```
//oda - oledbdataadapter
oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
oda.Fill(dt_Temp);
DataTable dt_costcode = new DataTable();
oda.Fill(dt_costcode);
DataTable dt_desc = new DataTable();
oda.Fill(dt_desc);
DataTable dt_unit = new DataTable();
oda.Fill(dt_unit);
connExcel.Close();
ViewState["TempImport"] = dt_Temp;

List<CostColumns> list_costCode = Columns(dt_costcode);
Bind_ddlCostCode(list_costCode);

List<CostColumns> list_desc = Columns(dt_desc);
Bind_ddlDescription(list_desc);

List<CostColumns> list_unit = Columns(dt_unit);
Bind_ddlUnitofMeasure(list_unit);
```

here code for binding Dropdowns:-

```
public void Bind_ddlCostCode(List<CostColumns> list_costCode)
    {
        foreach (CostColumns costcol in list_costCode.ToList())
        {
            if (costcol.ColumnType == "System.String")
            {
                ddlCostCodeNumber.Items.Add(new ListItem(costcol.Columns, costcol.ColumnType));
            }
        }
        ddlCostCodeNumber.DataBind();
        ddlCostCodeNumber.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select CostCode--", "0"));
    }
    public void Bind_ddlDescription(List<CostColumns> list_desc)
    {

        foreach (CostColumns costcol in list_desc.ToList())
        {
            if (costcol.ColumnType == "System.String")
            {
                ddlDescription.Items.Add(new ListItem(costcol.Columns, costcol.ColumnType));
            }
        }
        ddlDescription.DataBind();
        ddlDescription.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Desc.--", "0"));
    }
//(Same code for Bind_ddlUnitofMeasure(list_unit))
```

And here's where It all goes wrong:-

```
 protected void Btn_ImportRecords_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt_Temp= (DataTable)ViewState["TempImport"];
        DataTable dt_Import = new DataTable();
        Int32 i = costCodeNo();
        string ccn = ddlCostCodeNumber.SelectedItem.Text;//gives same selected option(CostCodeNumber)
        string desc = ddlDescription.SelectedItem.Text;//gives same selected option
        string unit = ddlUnitofMeasure.SelectedItem.Text;//gives same selected option
        dt_Import.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CostCodeNo", typeof(Int32)));
        dt_Import.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(ddlCostCodeNumber.SelectedItem.Text, typeof(string)));
        dt_Import.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(ddlDescription.SelectedItem.Text, typeof(string)));
       //throws exception that dt_Import already has same column name
}
```

[image: Selected different values]

Comment: aren't you filling all datatables with the same 'SelectCommand'?

Comment: @Dle Yes, I'm filling all datatables with same "SelectCommand"

Comment: Please show your definitions of the dropdown lists... combining `ddl....Items.Add` with `ddl....DataBind` looks wrong to me.

Comment: @grek40 I replaced Lists with datatable directly and instead of filling up column datatype in dropdownlist's selectedvalue I used Column name. My code worked smoothly. thanks for advice anyway.